# Iterating through a vector in x86?

Tags: assembly, x86

So, we're beginning to do small things in x86 but I can't grasp it at all. We have this:

```
  .Data
  frequency DW 0, 260, 300, 330, 350, 390, 440, 500, 520, 590, 660, 700
```

I have to iterate through it, seems simple for me, but:

```
  mov EAX, frequency  
  mov ECX, 0  // as a counter
```

Isn't correct, am I right? I was thinking about moving to `EAX` the address of frequency, but then again doesn't seem right to me.
Anyone can help me know how to do a simple [ `if != 700` ] loop?
Don't really care about the loop, just want to know how to get the elements on "frequency" into a register and then keep getting the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to assume that these values are stored contiguously in memory. Then you obtain a pointer to (address of) the first one, and iterate through them by continuously incrementing that pointer by the size of each element.

To know when to stop iterating (*i.e.*, for the loop termination condition), you can either use a counter (because you know that there are a constant 12 elements), or you can check the value to see if it is 700 (then you know you're at the end).

Here is an example that uses a counter:

```
    mov  ecx, 0                  ; initialize counter
    mov  edx, OFFSET frequency   ; get address of the first element
DoLoop:
    mov  eax, DWORD PTR [edx]    ; get value of the element
    ...                          ; do something with that value, now in the EAX register
    inc  ecx                     ; increment counter by one
    add  edx, 2                  ; increment pointer by size of an element
    cmp  ecx, 12                 ; compare counter against 12 (total number of elements)
    jl   DoLoop                  ; keep looping while less than 12
```

There are multiple ways to write this loop, some perhaps slightly more optimal than the above code, but that should give you the idea.

If you just want to do a simple "if x != 700" loop, then it is as simple as:

```
cmp  X, 700       ; where X is some register or memory location that you want to test
jne  BranchLabel  ; where 'BranchLabel' is the label to jump to if X != 700
```

In general, on x86, you will do a conditional branch using a [`CMP` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_35.html) to set the flags, followed by [a `Jcc` instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_146.html) that actually does the branching (where `cc` is a condition code that specifies how the flags are to be tested).

However, you do not have to use a `CMP` instruction. There are a bunch of other instructions that set flags, including `TEST` and nearly all of the arithmetic and bitwise instructions (*e.g.*, `ADD`, `SUB`, `XOR`, etc.) If the flags have already been set, then you can just do the `Jcc` directly. There is no need for a redundant comparison!

Comment: Perhaps a good idea to actually read a *word* in stead of a *dword* since you increment the pointer by 2 to get to the next element.

Comment: Whether it's a good idea or just a valid idea depends upon your specific target architecture. In many cases, on modern processors, this will actually be faster. But you're right, it would certainly have been *more clear* if I'd read a word-sized value.

Comment: `movzx eax, word ptr [edx]` isn't slower on current CPUs (running as a pure load in the load port), and avoids any risk of a cache-line split.  It only costs one extra byte of machine-code size vs. a dword `mov`.  If you mean `mov ax, [edx]` might be slower, then yes, [partial registers are generally to be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers) when you easily can.  P5 Pentium had slow movzx for some reason, but that's ancient history.  Modern CPUs simply handle it in a load port, no separate ALU uop required.

Comment: The comments in the code say `do something with that value, now in the EAX register`, but that's not true.  The high half of EAX holds garbage (the next element), because you didn't zero-extend it into EAX.  You're right that `mov ax, [edx]` would suck (false dependency), but `movzx eax, word ptr [edx]` is efficient, and doesn't risk a cache-line split.  (Or even a segfault if the array ends right before an unmapped page).

Answer (score 1):

You're right on the first one.

`mov EAX, frequency` gets the address for the first element.
`mov dx, [eax]` gets an element from the array.
`add eax, 2` moves to the next element.